# UIWebView not playing video loaded with NSMutabaleURLRequest

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, video-streaming, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying load NSMutableURLRequst in UIWebview. Webview not lading video content. 
if i tried to get data from NSMutableURLRequst and saved into DocumentDirectory webview playing video perfectly.But video files are very large size. I have to be play in Webview without downloading. I am unable to find the issue. Can any one please help in this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Code I have used:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request =  [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:GET_METHOD];
[request setValue:@"application/video" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
// setting header keys
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@“Authorization value” forHTTPHeaderField:@"authorizationKey"];
```

the above code is for creating Request.
I just simply load this request into UIWebview by usgin following line.

[videoWebView loadRequest:request]